# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.klarna.checkout:sdk:1.6.13

Tags: android

When ever I am trying to add dependency at gradle

```
implementation 'com.klarna.checkout:sdk:1.6.13'
```

it is throwing error

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.klarna.checkout:sdk:1.6.13
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read the code of conduct here https://stackoverflow.com/conduct and write question with problem and expected out along with some code if you tried any.

Answer (score 0):

check https://github.com/klarna/kco-mobile-sdk

You are missing the repository:

```
repositories {
    ....
    maven {
        url 'https://x.klarnacdn.net/mobile-sdk/'
    }
}
```